# Installing Ubuntu 13.10 with dvd

Tags: installation, dual-boot, wubi, dvd, livedvd

I'm a windows user thats wants to switch to Ubuntu as it is much better imo ( tried install with wubi (hd could only go up to 32gb)) so i decided to do a proper install using a dvd. I burned the dvd as an image as it should be done, following instructions, and when i turned my comp off and back on, it went straight to windows. from what i read, the dvd file should of loaded first allowing for the install. would appreciate any help possible. also my intent is to have dual-boot with both operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

The computer, in most cases, will boot off the HDD first.  Therefore, you will either have to change the boot sequence in the BIOS or choose which medium to boot off of.  The button F12 usually gives the option to choose which device to boot from.  The options available should be visible at the bottom of the screen when the computer boots up.

Answer (score 0):

If the disc is loaded before the computer starts (already in the drive) it should boot directly into the Ubuntu setup.
However, depending on your type of machine, you may have to select that as the boot disk, by entering the boot menu.
The key to press as your computer starts up to boot menu can be different and vary from machine to machine (can possibly be any key from ESC to f12, as posted above).